# wp_reset_query not resetting

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to query several different types of post on the same page.  When I try to query the second time (Essays), nothing shows up, meaning my `if ($arr_posts->have_posts())` is evaluating as false.  The first query and the third and fourth query are working fine. And the second query was working until I added this Interview query before it.  And even when I commented it out, it still stopped showing up.  What am I missing?  And `mwp_interview` is a custom post type.

```
<!--Latest Interview-->
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'mwp_interview',
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <div>
        DISPLAY INTERVIEW POST
    </div>
    <?php
endif; ?>

<!--Latest Essay-->
<?php
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'Essays in Discipleship',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <div>
        DISPLAY ESSAY POST
    </div>
    <?php
endif; ?>

<!--Latest Special Series-->
<?php
$ss_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'Special Post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
wp_reset_query();
$ss_arr_posts = new WP_Query( $ss_args );

if ( $ss_arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $ss_arr_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <div>
        DISPLAY SPECIAL SERIES POST
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
?>

<!--Latest Podcast-->
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'Podcast',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <div>
        DISPLAY PODCAST
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Wordpress documentation WP_Query Category Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).

> `category_name` (string) – use category slug.

The argument's name `category_name` is actually misleading, `category_name` is referring to the **category SLUG, NOT the actual category NAME**.

```
<?php
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'mwp_interview',
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ):
  $i = 0;
  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i > 1 )
      echo "<hr>";
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  endwhile;
else:
    echo 'No "interview" just yet!';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
$args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'category_name' => 'essays-in-discipleship', // ... must be set set to "Essays In Discipleship" category slug
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ):
  $i = 0;
  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i > 1 )
      echo '<hr>';
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  endwhile;
else:
    echo 'No "Essays In Discipleship" just yet!';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
$args = [
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'category_name' => 'special-post', // ... must be set to "Special Post" category slug
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ):
  $i = 0;
  while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i > 1 )
      echo '<hr>';
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  endwhile;
else:
    echo 'No "Special Post" just yet!';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  It actually was working the way I had it before, but I had changed my "Essays" slug a few days ago because it was interfering with the page of the same name. :)  I just hadn't noticed it missing on the homepage until today.  Updated and fixed!